# Build wixproj on VSTS

Tags: wix, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a wixproj on VSTS but so far I only got the following message:

> SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj(27,5): Error : The WiX Toolset v3 build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/

For my tests I have created a new wixproj with **Wix Toolset v3.11RC2** on my computer and linked it to a new repo on VSTS.

VSTS hosted agent have **Wix Toolset v3.10** [installed](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#software).

The VSTS build use a VS Build Task, with the build Platform set to `x86` in order to avoir the `AnyCPU` error.

I have tried with the Hosted and Hosted VS2017 agent but no luck and also tried the default Wix imports:

```
<Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' != '' " />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets') " />
```

And those recommended for VS2017:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(WixCATargetsPath)" Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' != '' " />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.CA.targets" Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.CA.targets') " />
```

Do I need to configure something or is it not possible at the moment?

Comment: See if updating your imports to full paths to the wix files lets you at least build. Then you know there's something up with the properties in your imports at least.

Comment: I don't know the path to MSBuild or Wix on a hosted agent, but if you have the info I am willing to try.

Comment: It looks like you need to include wix.targets and wix200x.targets and wix2010.targets with your project and import wix.targets. It will pick up the wix install location via registry search and then set up all the other paths. I think you still need to import wix.ca.targets because it exists in the wix toolset install. Try using the path "$(WIX)SDK\wix.ca.targets". $(WIX) should be the environment variable that points to the install location.

Comment: hopefully someone else who has actually used hosted agents to build wix projects can chime in with a better response, I'm basically just guessing based on the information I've been able to look at which wasn't much.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with $(MSBuildToolPath) and $(WIX) but no luck :'(
I will try with the V3.10 of Wix Toolset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install WiX Toolset **v3.10**. The **v3.11** project templates need corresponding toolset version (**v3.11**).

So, if you want to use v3.11, you need to setup a [on premise build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows). BTW, VS2017 needs v3.11 toolset.

Regarding for v3.10 toolset, don’t install [Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2015 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2015Extension), the WiX v3.10 extension is already provided, so just install Wix v3.10 toolset directly.

Simple steps for v3.10 if you have already install Wix Toolset Visual Studio extension:

1. Remove Wix Toolset VS extension
2. Uninstall WiX v3.10 toolset
3. Install Wix v3.10 toolset
4. Create a new Wix project in VS2015
5. Add to source control and build.

The similar issue: [The WiX Toolset v3 build tools must be installed to build this project after applying template](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5564).

Comment: I use VS2017 and Wix Toolset v3.11 because it is the recommended downloads, but they are not compatible right now with the hosted agent?

Comment: @JérémieBertrand Yes. You can setup a on premise build agent.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have tried to use Wix 3.10 and VS2017 but it seems that they are not compatible, so I will try to use VS2015 instead.
Do you know if/when VS2017 and Wix3.11 will be supported by the hosted agents?

Comment: @JérémieBertrand Since v3.11 toolset is RC version, I think the Hosted agent will be updated after the stable version of toolset be released. You can submit the user voice here if the hosted agent isn't updated after the stable version of toolset be released.(https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/category/145254-ci-build?query=Parameterize%20Azure%20subscription%20in%20VSTS%20build%20and%20release)

Comment: I confirm that it is working with the combo VS2015 + Wix3.10.
I will try to edit my existing projects to make it work as well :)

Comment: After a few tests, it is possible to have VS2017 + Wix3.11 in local and use VS2015+Wix3.10 for VSTS build, but you need to stick to VS2015 language supported stuff (like no pattern matching). 
you just have to use the declaration from Wix3.10 and suppress the ICE validation messages.
Right now it's working for a new project, but my existing project goes to infinite build on VSTS so there might be some more changes to make it work completely.

Comment: So it seems that there were warning message which hangs the build if Wix is not executed on another process.
You have to add <RunWixToolsOutOfProc>true</RunWixToolsOutOfProc> in the wixproj.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize my research after @starain-MSFT had answered:

It is possible to use VS2017 + Wix3.11 on your computer and build on VSTS with VS2015 + Wix3.10, you just have to:

- use the template from Wix3.10:

  ```
  <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
  <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>

   ...

  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
  ```
- avoid any [C# 7 specific](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/)

The property `SuppressValidation` set to true might help if you are  blocked by ICE warnings.

And if your build hang on VSTS, check the warnings on your computer or set the `RunWixToolsOutOfProc` property in your .wixproj to true.